# Dump H2 insert statements

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

Hi How can I dump data only for an instance of H2 In Memory DB.

What I currently have

```
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
            .prepareStatement("SCRIPT SIMPLE NOSETTINGS");
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String columnValue = resultSet.getString(1);
        out.print(columnValue);
        out.println();
```

This dumps the entire db structure however not just the insert data.  Basically what I want to do is backup the data I insert during development mode so the next time the database is started I can script the data back in.

The table structure isn't a problem as it is done by JPA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To filter out just inserts, you could use:

```
if (columnValue.startsWith("INSERT")) {
    out.println(columnValue);
}
```

Comment: Were you the person who put this in a comment earlier? I didn't get a chance to respond to that comment and I don't see it now.

Comment: Yes I first added it as a comment.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My export doesn't contain any INSERT statements.

Comment: That would have been easy! But I checked this already and no, my tables are populated with data. :-/

Comment: @PeterWippermann in this case I would need a simple, reproducible test case. Because i can't reproduce it.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Please forget what I said, I got my INSERT statements now. Don't know went wrong in the first place. Thanks anyway :-)